# In México how would a runner say "fartlek", "side-cramp", "long slow distance run", and cross country running?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico, méxico, deportes

If a cross country runner is out there I also want to know how to say what is called **fartlek**. A fast up tempo speed run followed by recovery running. It's interval training but no walking is allowed. Also is there a particular word for **a long distance run** and **cross-country running** (as in the sport name)? Also what is a **side cramp**, or **side-stitch** called, the pain in the side of your abdomen which is likely caused by lack of water, potassium or weak abdomen?

Comment: I believe [flato](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I3iVQ4z) may be what you are looking for as "side cramp or side-stitch".

Comment: It's a "calambre" but I think there's a word for it when it's in your abdomen during running.

Comment: @Diego I think you're right about [flato][https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flato_(dolor_abdominal)] now.

Comment: I would use "calambre" for a muscle, but "flato" for that particular pain on the side when running. Other users may be able to offer more accurate answers for when to use which.

Comment: @Die This is a good tool when I can't find it in the dictionary. I just realized I can search for something in wikipedia english and get the best word by swapping into spanish. Cross country is apparently Campo a través [https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campo_a_trav%C3%A9s].

Comment: @D That of course never beats a native born and raised in a region answering. Fartlek may have a different spanish word, because it's untranslated from the original swedish word Fartlek https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fartlek

Comment: Thank you for splitting this question into two. I think the questions are much better now, and easier for whoever is searching for the same answer to get to meaningful content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **long distance run**, the sports tech term you're looking for is ***Carrera de fondo***. Actually, any sports endeavor that rewards endurance over speed is said to be about *"fondo"* físico, literally *"bottom"* or *"deep end"* probably an allegory about finding one's physical *endurance depth.*

Anything **cross country** (running, walking, etc) is said to be ***Campo-traviesa***

As for **fartleks,** the English loan word ***"Sprint"*** will be well understood in Mexico with your intended meaning.

As for the side cramp, it's a funny idiom: ***"Dolor de caballo"*** or ***"caballazo"*** refers to that kind of pain, probably referring to the Broken stride when you get hit by that pain while running, that resembles a horse's stride.

For example: "No pude terminar la *carrera de fondo* a *Campo-traviesa,* pues al terminar el primer *sprint* me dió un insoportable *dolor de caballo*"

Comment: You got every one except one. Sprint is too short to be a fartlek. A fartlek run is like a long distance run where you alternate runing fast and then slow. Is there a word for that?

Comment: There's probably a specific word, however it may be a domain specific technical term. I'm sure, however, sprint will convey most of what you mean to most Mexican Spanish speakers :)

Answer (score 3):

For "fartlek" we use the same word: "fartlek". See https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fartlek:

> El Fartlek —«juego de velocidad» en sueco1 — es un sistema de entrenamiento que consiste en hacer varios ejercicios, tanto aeróbicos como anaeróbicos, principalmente ejercicios de carrera, caracterizados por los cambios de ritmo realizados a intervalos.

However, as far as I know, and unlike the other words you ask for, this is generally not used outside the running community, and therefore generally unknown.

Comment: perapera: parece que tienes distintas cuentas con el mismo usuario. Si fue por error, puedes leer [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) para solucionarlo.